# finding the ordered pair of $N \times N$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

find the number of order pairs  $(X,Y)$ where $X$ and $Y$ are $n\times n$ matrices such that $XY-YX =I$ is
choose the correct option

1. $0$
2. $1$
3. $n$
4. $\infty$

i was trying this question but my logic answer was $0$( zero)because i could not find this kind of matrices,,,i dont know whether my answer is correct or not im not sure,, if anyone help me i would like to thank him

i couldnot able to find this kind of matrices

Comment: This is quite hard to read .... is your question whether there are $n$-by-$n$ matrices with $XY-YX=I$, and if so, how many are there?

Answer (score 1):

$$trace(XY-YX)=trace(I)$$

$$trace(XY)-trace(YX)=n$$

$$0=n$$

hence we have a contradiction.

Comment: Zero can equal $n$ you know!

Comment: thanks a lot  @ siong thye Goh,,for clearing my doubts...